# Is it possible to hide a page in a PDF document using javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is it possible to hide a page in a PDF document using javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a PDF" exactly? Physically inside the file? While viewing it with the PDF viewer? Which one?

Answer (score 2):

If there is, it would be through the acrobat javascript API:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Layers to hide content in PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

HTML JavaScript cannot access objects within a PDF file.

This might be a start for you on the Acrobat Javascript
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf

> How can I hide an Acrobat form field based on the value of another?
>
> Use the display method of the Global object:

```
var title = this.getField("title");
if (this.getField("showTitle").value == "Off")
title.display = display.hidden;
else
title.display = display.visible;
```